# How do you customize Rotate, Scale and Grab?

Tags: edit-mode

I was doing some work on blender and I ran into a couple of problems.
1. You know Rotation and Scaling is a point. It usually rotates/scales from the center of the object. But mine now rotates about the 3D cursor.
2. Usually in Edit Mode you can go wild. You can change and modify points(vertices), edges or faces. But in trying to move a point or an edge, the whole object or very large parts of the object move.

I'll like that you help fix these problems. And when I started this project everything  was in place and worked according to how I was used to it. I know it changed because I clicked or pressed a button by mistake.
I tried to load factory settings, it instead  opened a new file.
Blender version 2.79

Answer (score 2):

1. Change Pivot point from this menu:

[image]

Also, you can switch between Bounding box and 3D cursor using <kbd>.</kbd>  (point on keyboard) and <kbd>,</kbd>(comma)

2. Turn off [Proportional editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html):

[image]

Also, you can turn on/off Proportional editing using <kbd>O</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I think you've modified two options.

1. Rotation and scale are relative to a pivot. By default this is the object center in object mode (or more exactly the median point is several objects are selected). But you can change it to either:

   - Active element: the pivot is considered to the active object of the selection (the one generally appearing with yellow borders)
   - Median point: the barycenter of the selected objects centers
   - Individual origins: each selected object is its own center
   - 3D cursor: the pivot is considered to be the cursor location
   - Bounding box center: the pivot is the center of the box enclosing the selection

These options can be found in the bottom of the 3D view:

[image]

2. In edit mode, you've probably set the proportional editing mode which can be set and unset using <kbd>O</kbd>

Generally this makes appear a circle. But if you are too close and the circle too large this is not visible.

[image]